# XAUTHORITY environment value is not a clean path

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, visual-studio-code

I am having trouble opening VS Code from my VM running on Ubuntu 16.04. When I try to open it from the terminal, I get the error:

> WARNING: XAUTHORITY environment value is not a clean path: "/some/path/.Xauthority"
>   cannot open path of the current working directory: Permission denied

I don't know much about what .Xauthority is, so unfortunately that is about all the information I can provide. The path seems legitimate, but if someone could help me out, that would be great.

Comment: I think I had one or two snap programs work/install, back in the early days.  There were always limitations.  I used to report the limitations as bugs.  I do not think they get followed-up.  If you report to the project eg. gnome-calculator, they probably say. "app works ok".  Perhaps the person to repor things to is the maintainer / assembler(???).  I got this error this weekend on Ubuntu **20.04"* (not so aged, really).  Fortunately(??) I get that error on "**Snap Store**" -- From now on, I'm addressing all bugs/limitation to Launchpad -- Seems the most appropriate.

Comment: Perhaps the problem consists of symbolic link use... It would be best to use a path without symbolic links or funny such as "../..".

Answer (score 0):

The `XAUTHORITY` warning is probably not directly related to permissions. It's related to whatever is the first part of your `$XAUTHORITY` path being a symlink. It can be safely ignored.

Not being able to access your current working directory might be how VS Code is installed, its (E)UID/(E)GID. You might have the VS Code snap installed as root. If your CWD is on a NFS share, check whether it is squashing root. Check the perms on the current working directory and your `/snap/bin/code` as well.